# Error: cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer in command line

Tags: dll, windows-8

I was using my command line on my Windows 8 pc, after I typed the ls command, then I got the following error:

ls.exe-System Error 
The program can't start because cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Actually, I have googled it and watched some vids, I have tried download a cygintl-2.dll zip file, then extracted the dll file then copy it to the system32 folder. However, it still display the error. I also tried to reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. it was failed also. I have no idea where I can find any help about this. Hope anyone can help me. Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the lack of `cygintl-2.dll`&`cygintl-1.dll` in OpenSSH/bin.

- try finding and downloading the two dlls then copy them into OpenSSH/bin (usually it is installed in /program files/openssh/bin, or you can check the environment path to find the installation path)

Answer (score 2):

I installed a newer version of OpenSSH and it fixed the problem thankfully. I was getting pretty worried! Specifically, I followed these two links (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/lsexe-system-error-how-to-browse-directories/2dddf4a5-5958-4768-acd7-ab4cf816f57e?auth=1 and https://sourceforge.net/p/sshwindows/bugs/2/) and then installed the executable from this site: http://sshwindows.webheat.co.uk/