# PHP shell_exec error after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10

Setup:
Windows 10 (Upgraded from Win7)
Xampp 
Apache 2.4.10 (Win32) 
PHP 5.5.15

I'm working on a php project that uses shell_exec. It worked before on Windows 7 but after I upgraded to Windows 10 it started getting this error.

[error screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpsFX.jpg)

ls.exe - System Error
The program can't start because cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer.

I could probably download the file somewhere but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: It seems to be a problem due to your Windows..Your Windows may be lacking some `DLL` files or in other words I would say that your Windows may be corrupted i.e you may have installed a window from a corrupted CD image or ISO image..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TO FIX YOUR `cygintl-2.dll` ISSUE :**

Download Your `DLL` File From Here :

http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=cygintl-2.dll&arch=32Bit&version&dsc#

**Note :** After downloading the `zip` file,Extract it and then open the `readme.txt` file and read it and so you will know where to put the file in your windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can see https://sourceforge.net/p/sshwindows/bugs/2/ and
[Error: cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366407/error-cygintl-2-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-in-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replies.

I just fixed it.

1. I downloaded the dll file from http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=cygintl-2.dll&arch=32Bit&version&dsc# (thanks Umair)
2. Placed it in folders where I thought it should go (under xampp installation).
3. Finally found the correct folder, xampp/php/

Comment: Sure, You are welcome. Make sure that you accept an answer for this question so that the question is considered solved.