# dll file missing when debugging for android in Qt

Tags: windows, qt, dll, system32

I have installed Qt for Windows 10 (64 bit) from [here](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.1/) (the [qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.10.1.exe](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.10/5.10.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.10.1.exe)). The problem is when I create a "QT Quick Application - Empty" and run it using the Android kit (Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.10.1 for Android armv7)) I get this window:

[image]

In english it says: "mkdir.exe - system error. Code execution could not be continued because the file cygintl-2.dll was not found. Re-installing the app may resolve the problem".

When I click OK I get the message "error: [install_target] Error 53" on the issues panel of qt creator.

This is the Compile Output:

```
Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=C:/Users/Thanasis/Documents/qt/build-map-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_10_1_for_Android_armv7-Debug/android-build" install
  3 [main] sh 7616 tty_list::allocate_tty: No tty allocated
Makefile:587: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 53
18:40:52: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project map (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.10.1 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Copy application data"
```

I have searched for this dll and downloaded it from [here](https://www.dll4free.com/cygintl-2.dll.html), then copied it in the System32 folder but the same error message pops up.

Comment: Seems something with the build path .. try to change the _Build directory_ of your project to a shorter path for example `c:\temp\myproject` ..

Comment: I tried it but I get the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally solved. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46030209/7053344) and installed openSSH from [this link](http://sshwindows.webheat.co.uk/) and it worked !!! :D